# How do I add spacing between a UITableView cell image/label and the separator?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with UIImage images populated in the cells. I want to be able to add some spacing between each image, and the separator lines because as you can see, some of the images are really close to the separator lines.

I could just modify the images and add spacing for each image, but I'd rather not.

Attached is what I like to achieve with the red arrows.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Added code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [sponsorsLogoArray count];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
    {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
    {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
    {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [ [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Set cell background color to be transparent as it cannot be achieved via storyboard
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Populate each cell with image from array
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[sponsorsLogoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Give contentOffset to the cell.

Comment: @divya can u explain what u mean? Thanks

Comment: In your code, you set [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero]; instead of these set top and bottom margin.

Comment: i don't know what you mean, please refer to my code to explain...thanks